# (PHP) Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: couldn't resolve host name

Tags: php, html, forms

I need some help fixing my code. I have looked around and can't get it to work. Here are the error messages I receive:

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: couldn't resolve host name in /home/a9317671/public_html/prox/get.php on line 13
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(http://http://ben-nottelling.comlu.com/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/a9317671/public_html/prox/get.php on line 13

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name='form' method='post' action="get.php">

ULR (no https/https): <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</body>
</html>
```

And the `get.php` code (this is were the problems occur):

```
<?php

$length = 10;

$fname= substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);


$name = $_GET['name'];
echo $name;

echo "The is a test. File will be at: http://ben-nottelling.comlu.com/prox/$fname.html";

file_put_contents($fname.html, file_get_contents("http://http://ben-nottelling.comlu.com/"));

?>
```

Comment: You have doubled `http://` protocol in the string.

Comment: I'm flagging this for "a simple typographical error" because the host was passed as a literal and the fix unlikely to help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you have used is wrong:

http://http://ben-nottelling.comlu.com/

should be:

http://ben-nottelling.comlu.com/

Next time debugging something like this. Try to see what the piece of code is doing and try it out manually, so in this case simply going to this url in the browser would give you some information.